# asiformdatarequest.m contain errors asihttprequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

Could someone tell me how I correct these errors in the class asiformdaterequest.m? Thanks !

[image: this is one of the images since I can not upload images for my reputation even then they are at this link]

[image: this the other image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please notice that [ASIHTTPRequest is no longer under support](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;)

You should use a alternative like:

[MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit)
or
[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/)

Answer (score 0):

Select your project, go to targets, go to build phases, go to compile sources, select all of the asi files, double click and enter the following in the box: -fno-objc-arc. You need to compile those without arc